# Data fetching of current login user in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello friends I am trying to fetch the data of current login user in laravel but I am getting the data of all users, I means that I have two tables.One is users tables which stores the data of login users and other table is publications tables, which stores the result of the the publications of the registerd users. How can I get the data of current login user's publications.while publications and users are cunnected through user_id foregion key.
My code is given here.

Publication.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')


<div class="container"><br>
    <h1 class="text-success text-center">Your Publications</h1><br>
    <table  class="table table-bordered">
        <tr class="">
            <th>Publication Title</th>
            <th>Publication Status</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>More Actions</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach($data as $value)
        <tr>
            <td> {{ $value ->title}}</td>
            <td>{{ $value ->status}}</td>
            <td>{{ $value ->year}}</td>
            <td><a href=""><button>Edit</button></a>&nbsp;<a href=""><button>Delete</button></a></td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach

    </table>
    <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Add more publications here</button> <button class="btn btn primary"><a href="home">Go Back to Dashboard</a></button><br>
    <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    <h3 class="text-success text-center">Complete your publication's detail</h3><br>
    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 m-auto d-block">
        <form action="pub" method="post">

            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">

            <div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Title </label>
                    <input type="text" name="title" id="" class="form-control">

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Conference / General </label>
                    <div class="radio form-control">
                        <label class="col-md-4"><input type="radio" name="status" value="conf" >Conference</label>

                        <label class="col-md-4"><input type="radio" name="status"  value="general">General</label>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="status" value="other" >Other</label>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Year: </label>
                    <input type="number" name="year" id="" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ADD!" class="btn btn-lg col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 m-auto d-block">
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
            </div>

    </div>
    </div><!--end demo-->


    @endsection
```

My model code is here publication.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class publication extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = ['user_id','title','status','year'];
}
```

The code of the PublicationController.php is given here. PLease help me that where is the problem.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\publication;
use Auth;
use DB;

class PublicationController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        return view('publications');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        publication::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'title' => request('title'),
            'status' => request('status'),
            'year' => request('year')
        ]);

        return 'inserted';
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show()
    {
        //
        $data['data'] = DB::table('publications')->get();
        if(count ($data)>0){
        return view('publications',$data);
        }
        else
        {
            return view('publications');
        }
    }


    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

The code of the web.php I means roots are here.

```
//for publications
Route::get('publications','PublicationController@index');
Route::post('pub','PublicationController@store');
Route::get('publications','PublicationController@show');
```

Both the tables users table and publications table are connected through foregion key user_id but I can not get the data of current login user data. it gives me all the data of stored in publications tabel.

Comment: you have 2 actions for same route `publications`

Comment: yes one for the storing data and one for fetching data

Comment: No `index` and `show` url is same . change for `show` or change for `index`

Answer (score 2):

this can help you, its working

```
   public function show()
     {
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    //
    $data['data'] = DB::table('publications')->where('user_id','=', $id)->first();
    if(count ($data)>0){
    return view('publications',compact('data'))
    }
    else
    {
        return view('publications');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get Login user's data.

First include this in your controller above class declaration

```
use Auth;
```

And then change your function `show` like below

```
public function show()
{
    //
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $data['data'] = DB::table('publications')->where('user_id' ,'=', $user_id)->get();
    if(count ($data)>0){
    return view('publications',compact('data'));
    }
    else
    {
        return view('publications');
    }
}
```

Comment: still getting the data of all register user's publications

Comment: change your line `return view('publications',$data);` to `return view('publications',compact('data'));` see in my edited answer

Comment: @IrfanKhan welcome. You can accept my answer and set it as solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your query in following way to add filter by user:

```
$userId = Auth::user()->id;
$data['data'] = DB::table('publications')->where('user_id', $userId)->get();
```

And you are using two similar routes just remove the one which is sending to index method.